# Telegram bot api, send message via @username

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

My telegram bot can communicate with users and I want to send results of their chat to admins telegram account.

I'm using `node telegram bot api` as my bot backend. How is it possible to send message to specific `@username` via telegram?

Comment: what I do is duplicate every message sent to the user to my own telegram, of course I have to type in my telegram chat id in the program line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiple strategies can be done to archieve that.

Simplest strategy from the top of my head is:

Initiate a conversation to the bot, send some password that identifies you as admin (i.e. using a custom `start` parameter https://telegram.me/ExampleComBot?start=vCH1vGWJxfSeofSAs0K5PA ) and store this chat_id somewhere as you know it is a `admin chat_id`. Then, everytime a user chats with the bot, use the bot to send the same message to `admin chat_id`.